# WordPress : The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, yoast

The AMP Plugin with the Yoast SEO Amp Glue plugin is generating these errors on some pages (about 10 on my site, but not all):

The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.
http://screencast.com/t/bXNcT67Ly

I'm not clear on what the error is.

The AMP Plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/

Answer (score 1):

I check your code, amp invalidates the page if it finds any `<script>` tag inside  tag. hence try to move the `<script>` tag in your source code to `<body>` tag, else if the js are been added by a plugin try disabling the plugin and validating your code and then move the `<script>` to `<body>`. for more errors troubleshooting about amp:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors.html
          https://asknoypi.com/accelerated-mobile-pages-validator/#script

Comment: Thank you ,, but i cannot disabling the plugin i need it ,, how can remove this in amp page ?